# Not understanding Type.IsAssignableFrom

Tags: c#, types

```
int i=1;
long longOne=i; //assignment works fine
//...but
bool canAssign=(typeof(long).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(int))); //false
```

Why is `canAssign` false?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you assign an `int` to a `long`, all that happens is implicit conversion. `longOne` is an actual `long` (as if you initialized it to be `1L`), and not an `int` masquerading as a `long`, if you get the drift.

That is, `int` (or `Int32`) and `long` (or `Int64`) aren't related in terms of inheritance or implementation; they just happen to be convertible because both are integral number types.

Answer (score 32):

Looking at the method in Reflector it would appear that this method is meant to be used for determining inheritance rather than compatibility.

For example if you have a class that implements an interface then the method would return true if you did 
`(typeof(interface).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(class))`

Answer (score 6):

The `IsAssignableFrom` returns true if the types are the same, or if the type implements or inherits it.

A `long` doesn't inherit `int`, so the method returns false.

When you assign an `int` value to a `long`, it's not just an assignment. The compiler also automatically adds code to convert the `int` value into a `long` value.

Answer (score 3):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx:

> true if c and the current Type represent the same type, or if the current Type is in the inheritance hierarchy of c, or if the current Type is an interface that c implements, or if c is a generic type parameter and the current Type represents one of the constraints of c. false if none of these conditions are true, or if c is null.

As @BoltClock says it is just implicit conversion.

Comment: This one always confuses me. I always forget which way to check (base to child or child to base). Leaving this here: `var isSameOrChild = baseType.IsAssignableFrom(otherType)`

Answer (score 3):

Because Type.IsAssignableFrom is a .NET framework facility, while assigning from int to long is a C# language one. If you take a look at the generated IL you'll see type conversion instruction there. There are lots of places where CLR rules might differ from C# ones, one more example is overload resolution in MethodBase.Invoke and the one performed by C# compiler.